# Twitter Data Mining: Degrees of separation

Tags: python, twitter, dump, social-graph

What ready available algorithms could I use to data mine twitter to find out the degrees of separation between 2 people on twitter.

How does it change when the social graph keeps changing and updating constantly.

And then, is there any dump of twitter social graph data which I could use rather than making so many API calls to start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a company offering a dump of the social graph, but it was taken down and no longer available. As you already realized - it is kind of hard, as it is changing all the time.

I would recommend checking out their social_graph api methods as they give the most info with the least API calls.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com)

**[What's the Data Mining Feed and can I have access to it?](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ&sp=1#WhatstheDataMiningFeedandcanInbsphaveaccesstoit)**

[The Data Mining Feed](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation&sp=2) is an expanded version of our /statuses/public_timeline REST API method. It returns 600 recent public statuses, cached for a minute at a time. You can request it up to once per minute to get a representative sample of the public statuses on Twitter. We offer this for free (and with no quality of service guarantees) to researchers and hobbyists. All we ask is that you provide a brief description of your research or project and the IP address(es) you'll be requesting the feed from; just fill out this form. Note that the Data Mining Feed is not intended to provide a contiguous stream of all public updates on Twitter; please see above for more information on the forthcoming "firehose" solution.

and also see: [Streaming API Documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation&sp=2)

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways of doing it but I've just spent the past 10 minutes looking at doing something similar and stumbled upon this Q.

I'd use an undirected (& weighted - as I want to look at location too) graph - use JgraphT or similar in py; JGraphT is java based but includes different prewritten algos.

You can then use an algorithm called BellmanFord; takes an integer input and searches the graph for the shortest path with the integer input, and only integer input, unlike Dijkstras.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

I used it recently in a project for flight routing, iterating up to find shortest path with shortest 'hops' (edges).